# A matter of indices - Electromagnetic Field Lagrangian

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, tensor-calculus, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I was trying to manipulate the following lagrangian :

$ L = -\frac{1}{4}F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu} $ where, of course, $ F^{\mu\nu} = \partial^\mu A^\nu - \partial^\nu A^\mu $.

The first steps are straightforward:

$ L = -\frac{1}{4}F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu} = -\frac{1}{4} (\partial^\mu A^\nu - \partial^\nu A^\mu)(\partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu) = -\frac{1}{4}(\partial^\mu A^\nu \partial_\mu A_\nu -\partial^\mu A^\nu \partial_\nu A_\mu - \partial^\nu A^\mu \partial_\mu A_\nu + \partial^\nu A^\mu \partial_\nu A_\mu) $

Then I've noticed that terms are pairwise equal: since the indices are all saturated, I've renamed $\mu$ as $\nu$ and viceversa in the last two terms. I've summed the first term with the last one and the two remaining:

$ L = -\frac{1}{2} (\partial^\mu A^\nu \partial_\mu A_\nu -\partial^\nu A^\mu \partial_\mu A_\nu)$

However if I apply the same "trick" in the second term, I get :

$ L = -\frac{1}2 \partial^\mu A^\nu (\partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu ) = -\frac{1}2 \partial^\mu A^\nu F_{\mu \nu} $

Comparing this expression with the original lagrangian, I conclude that $ \partial^\mu A^\nu = \frac{1}2 F^{\mu \nu}$, which makes no sense to me. The real problem is that from this expression I can calculate the correct form of the stress tensor :

$T^{\mu \nu} = \partial^{\nu}A_\lambda (F^{\mu \lambda}) - \frac{1}4 F^2 g^{\mu \nu}$

Can anyone point me out where I've made a mistake? I really can't wrap my mind around this discrepancy.

Comment: Typo in $F^{\mu \nu}$

Comment: Also the "trick" is fine, but concluding that $\partial^{\mu} A^{\nu} = \frac{1}{2} F^{\mu \nu}$ is incorrect, because you're missing the antisymmetry. Clearly when you remember the antisymmetrization you obtain the usual expression for $F^{\mu \nu}$.

Comment: @Eletie Thanks for your answer, but I still can't understand why my equation is incorrect. I mean, it's clear that $\partial ^\mu A_\nu$ must be antisymmetric (or else I would have a null lagrangian) and so it has the form $\partial ^\mu A_\nu = \partial^{[\mu} A_{\nu]} = \frac{1}2 (\partial ^\mu A_\nu - \partial ^\nu A_\mu )$. Isn't specifying $\partial ^\mu A_\nu = - \partial ^\nu A_\mu$  sufficient?

Comment: The equation you wrote first was fine, the conclusion is incorrect, because $\partial^{\mu} A^{\nu}$ is not antisymmetric. The Lagrangian would only be null if it were symmetric.

Comment: @Boreanaz To talk about symmetry on indices, both have to be up or down.

Comment: I think that @AFG answer explained my doubts and misunderstanding. I can't conclude that $\partial^\mu A^\nu$ is antisymmetric because the tensor contraction only involves its antisymmetric part (since $F^{\mu \nu}$ is antisymmetric). $\partial^\mu A^\nu$ does have a symmetric part, but I can't infer anything about it from my equations. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have an arbitrary tensor $T_{\mu\nu}$. It can be separated into the symmetric part and the antisymmetric part, i.e. $T_{\mu\nu}=T_{(\mu\nu)}+T_{[\mu\nu]}$. If you contract its indices with an antisymmetric tensor $B^{\mu\nu}$, you will have

$$T_{\mu\nu}B^{\mu\nu}=T_{[\mu\nu]}B^{\mu\nu}\tag{1},$$

but this does not mean that $T_{\mu\nu}=T_{[\mu\nu]}.$ The same happens with $\partial^\mu A^\nu$, its antisymmetric part is

$$\partial^{[\mu}A^{\nu]}=\frac{1}{2}\Big(\partial^\mu A^\nu-\partial^\nu A^\mu\Big)=\frac{1}{2}F^{\mu\nu}\tag{2}.$$

You can see that if you take $T_{\mu\nu}=\partial_\mu A_\nu$ and $B^{\mu\nu}=F^{\mu\nu}$, $(1)$ is satisfied:

$$\partial_\mu A_\nu F^{\mu\nu}=\frac{1}{2}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu},$$

and that is what you got for your Lagrangian.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer elucidated the problem completely!

Comment: You're welcome! You can accept the answer by clicking the "check" :)